# Remove class using javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to remove the specific class attribute from all the element in the page. That is we need to remove the particular class from all the elements of the current html page. We only have the class name as the reference (which we need to remove from that page) and nothing else.

Please note that **i cannot use anything as reference like id or another class** and also i cannot use any JavaScript libraries for this also...

Any suggestion on this would be greatly appreciated.

Also note that the class we need to remove will not be there more than twice.

Comment: Please provide some code describing your html structure so we'll be more likely to be of help

Comment: Remove the class from *what* element? All of them? Some of them? Under what circumstances, or what events? ...and I'm fascinated by the up-vote to the question.

Comment: It's not clear. Do you want to remove a specific "class name" from elements that have that class (so, you know what you're going to remove) or what else? You want remove all the whole class attribute from all the elements of the page? What is identifying "a specific class attribute"?

Comment: Love the edit, it clarifies **everything**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function removeClass(className) {
    // convert the result to an Array object
    var els = Array.prototype.slice.call(
        document.getElementsByClassName(className)
    );
    for (var i = 0, l = els.length; i < l; i++) {
        var el = els[i];
        el.className = el.className.replace(
            new RegExp('(^|\\s+)' + className + '(\\s+|$)', 'g'),
            '$1'
        );
    }
}
```

and just use it as :

```
removeClass('desired-class-name');
```

**UPDATE** :  see the live demo : http://jsbin.com/eyuxur

Comment: Did you read the question? The second sentence?

Comment: @DavidThomas well... in order to remove the class from the elements, you need to **know** that class. and be aware that my code does not require any "anything as reference like id or **another** class".

Comment: Your code does not work reliably, the attribute value "foobarbaz" will be replaced with "foobaz" if you attempt to remove "bar".  Also, you should use the `className` property which is live, instead.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a live collection. When you remove the class you filtered with from an element, the indexes will shift by one, rendering the rest of the loop all wrong. You should be iterating *backwards*.

Comment: @PointedEars, what exactly is the problem with `getAttribute('class')` (as opposed to `className`)?

Comment: see updates. It's not a live collection anymore and it does not replace the className if it's part of any other class names.

Comment: :)) the **^** sign is not only for beginnings :P. It can be used at the start of the square brackets to negate their content : http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html/

Comment: @katspaugh The `className` property yields the *current* white-space separated list of class names (it "is live"). `getAttribute("class")` returns the value of the `class` attribute of the element *as it was in the original source*. More recent user agents may have "fixed" this (I find it useful to be able to get the original value), but you cannot rely on that. Keep in mind that MSHTML is confused about what is an attribute and what is a property (as many people are), but other layout engines are not.

Comment: CSS class names may contain non-ASCII characters. [`\w` is only equivalent to `[0-9A-Za-z_]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp), so `[^\w]` (which is equivalent to `\W`) matches too much. See `jsx.dom.css.removeClassName()` in [JSX:css.js](http://pointedears.de/websvn/filedetails.php?repname=JSX&path=%2Ftrunk%2Fdom%2Fcss.js) for a possible fix.

Comment: @PointedEars, oh I see what you mean. If someone changes the class as a property, the attribute representation might not be updated. Thanks!

Comment: −1 lifted because it can work. But no +1 because I still would not do it this way. Not only are you working with a native method on a host object, but also copying the elements of a NodeList or collection can be very expensive. Just iterate backwards as katspaugh suggested, and you'll be fine even with a live _NodeList_ (_not_: collection).

Answer (score 9):

If you're using a modern browser:

```
var forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
var className = "yourclass";

forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("." + className), function(node) {
    node.classList.remove(className);
});
```

See: [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll) and [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.classList) for further details.

Comment: The classList property is not supported by IE9 and lower

Comment: @bhavya_w that's why I started with "*if* you're using a *modern* browser". Plus, the [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.classList) link I posted in the answer, provides a cross-browser implementation (given IE>7).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way which can be slow on very large pages, but removes the class from all elements.

```
var list = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
for(var i=0; i < list.length; i++){
  list[i].className = list[i].className.replace('YourClassName','');
}
```

Comment: You are using `className`, which is good, but same problem as with gion_13's code.