# Unable to addClass using Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I would like to style all the empty textboxes,by adding a class on validation (i.e on Submit), but my code isn't working. Not sure if its the script or the customvalidator. I only want to use JS.
If I say

```
target.style.border="1px solid red";
```

its working though. Just unable to add the class.

JS:

```
<link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
 function validateTextBox(sender, args) {
        var target = document.getElementById(sender.controltovalidate);
        var is_valid = target.value != "";
        if (is_valid) {
            target.removeClass("validate");
        }
        else {
            target.addClass("validate");
        }
        args.IsValid = is_valid;
    } 
</script>
```

ASPX:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtSurname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:CustomValidator ID = "CustomValidator1" runat="server" 
 ControlToValidate="txtSurname" ValidateEmptyText="true" 
 ClientValidationFunction="validateTextBox"
 ></asp:CustomValidator>
```

CSS:

```
 .validate
 {
   border:2px solid red;
 }
```

Comment: Also tried (sender.controltovalidate)

Comment: When I say, else {
            target.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        }    it works. Why is not adding the class

Comment: JS side of the code looks fine. It is recommended to use '!==' instead of '!='. Are you getting the textbox's reference in sender.controltovalidate.ClientID ?

Comment: @Rajat. I do not how to check if its getting the ref. but the bgcolor applied to multiple textboxes. I just need to add the class now

Comment: why don't you do a console.log(target)? That will confirm it. My suspicion is that target is not having the textbox reference.

Comment: Thank you. I do not know how to do that. But When it can apply bgcolor, to multiple textboxes, it is getting references. Am I right

Comment: I see. see my answer below. That could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

document.getElementById returns a DOM element, which does not have addClass or removeClass APIs.

see: [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/element)

To apply class, try (putting the idea, please tweak according to exact business logic):

```
target.className = target.className + " validate"
```

If we go with raw JS, we have to write raw code and forget luxuries of addClass or removeClass :-)
To remove class, see this answer:
[Remove class using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11494266/remove-class-using-javascript)

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked. I added a blank class to the textbox (class=""). Now, to add class it is target.className = "validate"; For removing it is target.className = "";

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
function validateTextBox(sender, args) {
        var target = document.getElementById(sender.controltovalidate.ClientID);
        if (target.value != "") {
            target.removeClass("validate");
        }
        else {
            target.addClass("validate");
        }
        args.IsValid = "";
    }
```

Comment: aren't you reversing the logic ? should it not be:
if (target.value !== "") //remove class

Comment: oh sorry it should be if (target.value != ""),

Comment: Tried your suggestion.No Luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Simple way .

```
function validateTextBox() {
        var target = document.getElementById("#<%= txtSurname.ClientID %>");
        **var is_valid = target.value;**
        **if (is_valid!="") {**
            target.removeClass("validate");
              **return true;**
        }
        else {
            target.addClass("validate");
            **return false**
        }

    }
```

ASPX:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtSurname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:CustomValidator ID = "CustomValidator1" runat="server" 
 ControlToValidate="txtSurname" ValidateEmptyText="true" 
 ClientValidationFunction=**"Javascript:return validateTextBox()"**
 ></asp:CustomValidator>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you would like to use [jquery validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)? This is widely used plugin.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSurname" runat="server" CssClass="toValidate"></asp:TextBox>

jQuery(function() {
    // You can specify some validation options here but not rules and messages
    jQuery('form').validate(); 
    // Add a custom class to your name mangled input and add rules like this
    jQuery('.toValidate').rules('add', { 
        required: true
    });
});
```

This code should check if textbox are empty before form submition.

Answer (score 0):

change `var target = document.getElementById(sender.controltovalidate.ClientID);`

to: `var target = document.getElementById(sender.ClientID);`

Comment: No Errors. It Just didt give the desired output.

Comment: Your css in embeded in the HTML or is it on a seperate file?

Comment: oh.U have a point. Its in a separate file. But I do have <link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><script>....  I'll update my Question