# jQuery RemoveClass/addClass analog Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have

```
$('.loading-overlay').removeClass('hidden');
```

and I have to rewrite the code without jQuery. How can this be done?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove class using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11494266/remove-class-using-javascript)

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please provide more details.

Comment: Hints: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2155787/921204 - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing:

```
document.getElementById("yourElement").className = "";
```

Assigning new one:

```
document.getElementById("yourElement").className = "yourNewClass"
```

Though, this method removes all classes.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("elementId").className =
document.getElementById("elementId").className.replace(/\burClassName\b/,'');
```